# React Native XHR multipart/form-data send data as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to send a multipart/form-data from React Native (Running on Simulator) to backend server using XHR with the following code

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://....url....');
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('title','This is awesome');
xhr.send(formdata);
```

However in console log the Request Payload are shown as **[object Object]**

So I decided to take the same code and put it in an HTML file and run from Chrome browser and Request Payload from console log is showing as below which I was expecting it from React Native

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryGXwudBdBkJzBnPug
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

This is awesome
------WebKitFormBoundaryGXwudBdBkJzBnPug--
```

Comment: Why do you use xhr ? You could use superagent for example which is a very good library to make requests

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and after a day of research I found that we have to apply a polyfill, because React Native environment differs from what you can find in browser or Node.js.

Put this line in your main index file, and you should be good:

```js
global.FormData = global.originalFormData ? global.originalFormData : global.FormData;
```

for TypeScript define `global` first:

```
declare const global: any;
```

Comment: In my case, I already had thse in the `index.js`.
I had to remove them for the upload to work!

Comment: I added this and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

To be complete: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/38 and https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/network-inspect-of-chrome-devtools.md should solve your problem

In short: `global.FormData = global.originalFormData`